# pfctl to add rules at runtime WITHOUT editing /etc/pf.conf?

Tags: macos, firewall, pfctl

I have an app that (while it is running and only while it is running) needs to make changes to the packet filter (`pf`) so that it blocks or allows certain traffic. These rules should be in addition to the user's own rules in `/etc/pf.conf` - but i do not want to directly edit `/etc/pf.conf` as this is extremely intrusive.

I can do this trivially in linux using `iptables` and even in windows using `wfp` without altering any on-disk files, can i accomplish the same thing in osx with `pf` ?

Solution only has to work in `yosemite` (10.10) and above

Comment: Hi, I wonder if you have found a way to achieve this goal by now ... I'm struggling with the same scenario. if you did, please share :-) thanks

Comment: @Zohar81sure i figured it out, do this: `cat /etc/pf.conf my_rules.conf | sudo /sbin/pfctl -Ef -`

The `-` arg to `pfctl` causes it to read from stdin, so we just concat pf.conf with our own rules to get it to read from both, but to ensure our rules take precedence (that's why our rules are concatenated last)

Comment: @Zohar81 also see my answer below

Comment: Perhaps are you also familiar of an option to get notification if some other root process call `pfctl` with difference configuration that override yours? I can do periodical check with the currently applied rules, but I wish I could get notification right when it changes... any idea how ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this myself.

```
cat /etc/pf.conf my_rules.conf | sudo /sbin/pfctl -Ef -
```

Where `my_rules.conf` contains our own rules, these get concatenated to the `pf.conf` rules but take precedence due to them being appended after `pf.conf` in the `cat` command.

Also note we use `pfctl -Ef -`  the `-` forces `pfctl` to read from stdin

We can take this solution a step further and load our own rules from stdin by using this:

```
echo "block out all" | cat /etc/pf.conf - | sudo /sbin/pfctl -Ef -
```

Comment: What does the `-E` does? The `man pfctl` doc is not very clear: it says that it enables the filtering like `-e` but it also says: "(...) and increment the pf enable reference count." and I did not get what this is exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of application and programming language.
The true programmatically way would be to open `/dev/pf` and use `ioctl`.
I haven't done this myself, but the following links should be helpful.

- https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-7195.81.3/bsd/net/pfvar.h.auto.html
- https://man.openbsd.org/pf
- https://github.com/mullvad/pfctl-rs

If calling `pfctl` from the app is sufficient, then I would still use anchors.

Without a file:
`echo "block out all" | sudo /sbin/pfctl -a 'com.apple/app_name' -f -`

With a file:
`sudo /sbin/pfctl -a 'com.apple/app_name' -f /path/to/file`